# Scheme code for Pollard's Rho algorithm

Tags: scheme

I am trying to learn scheme by implementing few algorithms.

```
Pollards-Rho(n)
 g(x) = x2 + 1 mod n
    x ← 2; y ← 2; d ← 1;
    While d = 1:
        x ← g(x)
        y ← g(g(y))
        d ← gcd(|x - y|, n)
    If d = n, return failure.
    Else, return d
```

I am trying to implement the above algorithm in scheme. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Alright, I answered your last question because I was interested, but in general, just asking people to write code for you is not acceptable here. What have you tried so far? What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: You can't just post the pseudocode from wikipedia and ask us to implement it for you.

Comment: I have already implemented these algorithms in Java and C#. Was curious how these work in Scheme. I learn quickly by seeing the implementation for the algorithms I know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not Rosetta Code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An implementation in Racket:

```
;;; ALGORITHM 19.8  Pollard's rho method
; INPUT   n>=3 neither a prime nor a perfect power
; OUTPUT  Either a proper divisor of n or #f
(: pollard : Natural -> (U Natural False))
(define (pollard n)
  (let ([x0 (random-natural n)])
    (do ([xi x0 (remainder (+ (* xi xi) 1) n)]
         [yi x0 (remainder (+ (sqr (+ (* yi yi) 1)) 1) n)]
         [i  0  (add1 i)]
         [g  1  (gcd (- xi yi) n)])
      [(or (< 1 g n) (> i (sqrt n)))
       (if (< 1 g n)
           (cast g natural?)
           #f)])))
```

Comment: It's a good idea to acknowledge your sources (cc-by-sa 3.0 with *attribution required*).  So I've upvoted but hazard a guess that you've taken this code [from here](https://github.com/racket/math/blob/master/math-lib/math/private/number-theory/number-theory.rkt#L352).  Any correction to my guesswork will be appreciated.

Comment: Of course. I am the author of that code.